# Merge two tables from two databases in different servers

Tags: sql-server, merge, synchronization, merge-conflict-resolution, offlineapps

I am developing a mobile app that will be able to work in offline mode.

I have an online application that consumes a table called "Books" in a database located on a server, and my mobile app has a sqlite database with the exactly table "Books".

When the app gets internet avaible, it syncs the data from "Books" table - located in sqlite - to "Books" table - located in SQL Server.

I am using the [MERGE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) statement to perform it. But I have a problem.

Imagine my mobile app is without internet connection for 7 days and the tables are:

```
Books(SQL Server)
+----+---------------------------------+--------------+
| Id | Name                            | LastModified |
+----+---------------------------------+--------------+
| 1  | Modern Operating Systems        | 2019-09-20   |
+----+---------------------------------+--------------+
| 2  | The Art of Computer Programming | 2019-09-20   |
+----+---------------------------------+--------------+
```

```
Books(sqlite in mobile App)
+----+---------------------------------+--------------+
| Id | Name                            | LastModified |
+----+---------------------------------+--------------+
| 1  | Modern Operating Systems        | 2019-09-20   |
+----+---------------------------------+--------------+
| 2  | The Art of Computer Programming | 2019-09-20   |
+----+---------------------------------+--------------+
| 9  | Computer Networks               | 2019-09-26   |
+----+---------------------------------+--------------+
```

Consider that both tables in sqlite and SQL Server contains Auto Increment Primary Key, if use the "Id" as the criteria of merge, it would get a dirty merge.

How should I do the merge in this case ?

Comment: You can't use an `int` id as you single PK when running a distributed system. Easy solution is use uniqueidentifier. Another solution is allocating different ranges of numbers to each database. Another solution is having a composite OK with a database id + sequence number.

Comment: ^ Composite PK.

Answer (score 0):

Using a composite primary key solves my problem.